Zapier deprecating Highrise CRM - any work around for triggers?
I’m not sure how many users still use Highrise, but my company of 17 still uses it. We’ve used Zapier to sync with other software such as AirTable and Quickbooks Online. Unfortunately, Zapier sent an email this week stating that it plans to remove Highrise in December 2024.
Highrise doesn’t support webhooks and I’m trying to rewrite a polling trigger with a custom API call.
With the current Zapier integration, it works as follows:

It polls my Highrise account every 15 minutes and if I add the tag “Prospect” to a contact, it triggers the scenario.

I’ve read Highrise API and I see the option to:

GET a list of contacts with the tag “Prospect”, for example.

But I don’t know a way to find a contact who has been recently tagged “Prospect” in the previous 15 minutes. I can, however, see if a contact has been modified but I’m not sure that’s helpful since so many items can be modified for a contact.
I believe it shares a similar platform with basecamp so I’m hopeful someone has a solution or a better idea than me. I’d prefer to move the custom API call to Make or somewhere else but I’d be open to keeping Zapier if that was the best solution.

You can use the "Retrieve Poll" option in the Webhooks by Zapier app to GET the list of Contacts from the Highrise API.
It'll function similarly to the Polling Trigger that the Highrise integration had.
Cheers!
Daniel - Zapier Support
